# Дойти до дома/до дому

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика

Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно писать/говорить: "дойти до дома" или "дойти до дому", "добраться до дому" или "добраться до дома"? Если первое, то понятно - дойти до чего? До дома, до своего дома, но часто слышу второе. Если второе - то почему?

Answer (score 3):

Оба варианта корректны.

*Дойти до д**о**ма* (до определенного дома) - *дойти д**о** дому* (дойти домой).

§ 150. Окончания родительного падежа единственного числа существительных мужского рода -а(-я) – -у(-ю)

<...> Форма на -у(-ю), с присущим ей разговорным оттенком, встречается в следующих случаях:
<...>

7) в некоторых случаях возможно смысловое различие форм на -а(-я) и на -у(-ю). Так, *выйти из дому* значит *«выйти из своего дома»* (т. е. места, где человек проживает), а *выйти из дома* может обозначать «выйти из строения определенного типа» или «выйти из обозначенного дома» (ср.: из дома вышли два гражданина; кто-то вышел из дома № 15).***

Ср. также:

*уйти из дому* (на некоторое время) – *уйти из дома* (покинуть семью);

*проводить д**о** дому* (проводить домой) – *проводить до д**о**ма* (до определенного дома).

Следует заметить, что формы на -у(-ю) в современном языке убывают и в разговорной речи и в художественной литературе. Что касается таких стилей, как научный и деловой, то эти формы находят в них ограниченное использование.

> См.: ***Д. Э. Розенталь. Справочник по правописанию и стилистике***

См.также:

дом, -а; *выйти из д**о**ма* (из здания), но ***и***з дому (из своего жилища); *дойти до д**о**ма* (до здания), но *д**о** дому* (до своего жилища); *смотреть на д**о**м,* но *брать работу н**а** дом* (домой); флаги на д**о**ме, но работать на дом**у** (дома); в поэтич. речи встречается *в дому*.

> Русское словесное ударение. Словарь нарицательных имён.
>   Автор М. В. Зарва.
>   Печатное издание М.: ЭНАС, 2001.
>   © Электронная версия, «ГРАМОТА.РУ», 2001–2002.

Answer (score 2):

Предлог *до* употребляется с формой родительного падежа. Таким образом, верно говорить и писать: дойти/добраться *до дома*. Вариант *до дому* является просторечным, рекомендовать его нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

Случайно обратил внимание, что ответа-то правильного на это вопрос нет.

Вариант **до дому** вполне правильный, но имеет смысловые и стилистические особенности.

До дому, до лесу, до свету и т. п. - по сути рудиментарные проявления в русском самостоятельной древней падежной формы. Обычно используются в наречном значении до дому = домой, до свету = рано утром и т. п. и имеют предложное ударения. Для передачи разговорной, поэтической, народной и любой другой, кроме книжной, сугубо академической, речи вполне естественны.

Другое дело, что в значении "дошел до строения" такой вариант вполне можно считать просторечным (вряд ли "грубо неправильным") или украинизмом. Но только в этом значении, локализующем точку на местности, а не место обитания.

Answer (score 0):

Со всеми согласна. Но до дома - до определённого объекта. До дому - попасть домой.

Comment: *Дойти до дому* (в любом значении) – грубое просторечие, выходящее за рамки языковой нормы. Разумеется, никто не может запретить конкретному человеку говорить именно так, а не иначе. Но при этом он должен быть готов к тому, что его сочтут человеком низкой культуры. Вот и всё, собственно.

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку есть и будет длинный ряд предложных сочетаний (*пропасть из виду, беситься с жиру, хотеть до зарезу, болтать без умолку*), поскольку никуда не денутся фразеологизмы (*без году неделя, с глазу на глаз, задать перцу, добиться толку, что есть духу*), и те, что с оттенком количественного значения (чашка чаю, ложка сахару), то, конечно, «до дому, до хаты» ещё поживут. Но недолго. ***Идти до дому*** со смыслом «идти домой» говорить ненормально.